# Tensorflow import error after building from source

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built tensorflow with GPU support from source from this release https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.13.0-rc0 and everything worked without issue however when I imported tensorflow in python I get the errors

```
>>> import tensorflow
ImportError: No module named _multiarray_umath
ImportError: No module named _multiarray_umath
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: No module named protobuf
```

I do have protobuf installed.  Also I an using ubuntu 16.04 with CUDA 10. Doe anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: Are you sure you installed protobuf into the same version of Python you tried this import with?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I found the solution here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6341

but basically its just

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip uninstall google
pip install google
pip install protobuf
```